# Node.js crashes! SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: node.js, crash, express

Suddenly nothing works. The only thing I did was adding a new file to the folder "controllers", and then removed it. What can be wrong? What does it mean?

```
node/last/test4/controllers/.DS_Store:1

^

module.js:311
    throw err;
          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:429:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at /Users/henrikpetersson81/node/last/test4/controllers.js:8:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.oncomplete (node/last/test4/controllers.js:6:15)
```

controllers.js (nothing is changed in this file since it worked):

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(app, service){
    fs.readdir(__dirname + '/controllers', function(err, files){
        if (err) throw err;
        files.forEach(function(file){
            var name = file.replace('.js', '');
            require('./controllers/' + name)(app, service);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its because Mac created a file `.DS_STORE`. Whats happening is a helper is automatically going through the controllers folder and including them. Node has included it thinking is a controller and crashed because it's not JavaScript.

Comment: Or change the code to ignore any file whose filename starts with a dot. Those files are traditionally hidden in UNIX; they're probably not controllers you actually want to load.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the file and deleted it. However, now I get another error message (see the updated question). App.js is in the root of the project and has never been in ./controller, so that's really strange :/

Comment: It's trying to include app.js as a module as per this line: `require('./controllers/' + name)(app, service);` but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Haha, never mind my last comment, I was in the controllers folder when trying to start node ;) ! I'm getting tired after +10h of coding lol.